How to use a comma as a decimal seperator in Oracle Apex?
We use commas as our decimal seperator in my company and I am trying to incorporate this in our apex form but it's automatically rounding the numbers up or own to a whole number when an excel is imported with that number column. I realize that a way around this is to set the column as a text field but then the issue is because these decimals are used in mathemetical functions which then don't work it's text and not a number.
What I'm thinking is maybe a convertion from text to decimal with a "dot" as a seperator, ergo 4,2 --> 4.2 and then use that temporary variable in our function.
Example:


var num1 = document.getElementById('P19_MENGE_1').value;
var num2Text = document.getElementById('P19_KI').value; // Get the text value
var num3 = document.getElementById('P19_PF').value;

// Replace commas with periods in num2
var num2 = parseFloat(num2Text.replace(",", ".")); // Convert to a number with the decimal point

// Convert text inputs to numbers with error handling
function toNumber(value) {
    const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
    if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
        console.error(`Invalid number: ${value}`);
        return 0;
    }
    return parsedValue;
}

num1 = toNumber(num1);
num2 = toNumber(num2);
num3 = toNumber(num3);

if (num1 === 0 || num2 === 0 || num3 === 0) {
    document.getElementById('P19_ANZ_PAL').value = "";
} else {
    const result = num1 / num2 / num3;
    document.getElementById('P19_ANZ_PAL').value = result.toFixed(1);
}



what happens right now is the decimal gets removed when I click on save so 42,5 goes to 425 and the result is calculated with that 425...

The only problem I see, is that your code does not replace commas in num1 and num3, so your parseFloat() removes the part of the number after the comma.
See the two lines after my EDIT comment for the added code for replacing comments.
The html and recalculateOnClick() were only added for this snippet.


var num1 = document.getElementById('P19_MENGE_1').value;
var num2Text = document.getElementById('P19_KI').value; // Get the text value
var num3 = document.getElementById('P19_PF').value;

// Replace commas with periods in num2
var num2 = parseFloat(num2Text.replace(",", ".")); // Convert to a number with the decimal point

// EDIT You need to replace commas in the other two numbers
num1 = parseFloat(num1.replace(",", "."));
num3 = parseFloat(num3.replace(",", "."));

// Convert text inputs to numbers with error handling
function toNumber(value) {
    const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
    if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
        console.error(`Invalid number: ${value}`);
        return 0;
    }
    return parsedValue;
}

num1 = toNumber(num1);
num2 = toNumber(num2);
num3 = toNumber(num3);

if (num1 === 0 || num2 === 0 || num3 === 0) {
    document.getElementById('P19_ANZ_PAL').value = "";
} else {
    const result = num1 / num2 / num3;
    document.getElementById('P19_ANZ_PAL').value = result.toFixed(1);
}


// EDIT Added for testing purposes
function recalculateOnClick( event ) {
  // Replace commas with periods
  let num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('P19_MENGE_1').value.replace(",", "."));
  let num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('P19_KI').value.replace(",", "."));
  let num3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('P19_PF').value.replace(",", "."));

  num1 = toNumber(num1);
  num2 = toNumber(num2);
  num3 = toNumber(num3);

  if (num1 === 0 || num2 === 0 || num3 === 0) {
      document.getElementById('P19_ANZ_PAL').value = "";
  } else {
      const result = num1 / num2 / num3;
      document.getElementById('P19_ANZ_PAL').value = result.toFixed(1);
  }
}
input {
  width: 4rem;
}

hr { 
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
Num 1 <input id="P19_MENGE_1" type="text" value="170,12">
Num 2 text <input id="P19_KI" type="text" value="2,01">
Num3 <input id="P19_PF" type="text" value="0,753">
<hr>
Result <input id="P19_ANZ_PAL" type="text" value="753">
<hr>
<button onclick="recalculateOnClick(event)">Recalculate</button>



